# Want to Disable transparent div at the time of page loading & show after page load

Tags: css, cakephp-1.3

HI I have written code of a transparent div which I am using back of some text(message) of website's home page to show text more bright:

```
#transdiv {
 position:absolute;
top:228px;
width:852px;
height:160px;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.3);
border-radius:8px;
```

}
& I am using in home page & code like this:

```
<div id="spotlight" class="pagewidth">
    <div id="find-mentor">
       <div id="transdiv">

                 <h1><?php echo Configure::read('SearchBarHeading');?></h1>
        <h2><?php echo Configure::read('SearchBarSubheading');?></h2>
        <div id="text-box">
```

But now my problem is this I want that this div should upload after the other content load on home page but the thing is it upload very first on page some time which looks very bad so I need to fix this & make it load later after all other content of page has loaded.
Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Use `JavaScript` and keep the `div` initially hidden and on the page load event show it using `JS` code.

Answer (score 0):

Java Script is only way i believe.
Simply You add another class to element when document is ready (dom has fully loaded). This class will make element visible. Visibility instead of display is used to make element take its space event before it's shown.

here's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/22Qh2/

and here's the JS code:

```
window.onload=function(){
    addClass(document.getElementById('transdiv'),'shown');
};

/*  functions handling classes in js */
function hasClass(el, name) {
   return new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+name+'(\\s|$)').test(el.className);
}
function addClass(el, name){
   if (!hasClass(el, name)) { el.className += (el.className ? ' ' : '') +name; }
}
function removeClass(el, name){
   if (hasClass(el, name)) {
       el.className=el.className.replace(new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+name+'(\\s|$)'),' ').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
   }
}
```